# ORA-06502 Error when creating a view

Tags: sql, view, oracle10g

I am trying to create a view on my production server which will not compile -- however, the view already exists on our test server with no error.

I am getting this error:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 27
```

However, whats very confusing is the fact that the error itself points to the view column definition.  I'm not really sure how to approach this, again considering the fact that the same routine exists in our test environment with no issues.

Here is the view, with a warning that it is pretty large:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW V2RPT.VW_DM
(
   ACCESSION_LABEL, 
   RECEIVED_DATE,
   ACCESSIONING_TS,
   TTR_TUMOR_TYPE_INFO,
   SPEC_TYPE,
   TUMOR_TYPE,
   TUMOR_SUBTYPE,
   PRIM_MET,
   TUMOR_SITE,
   EXTRACT_DATE,
   CELL_SOURCE_STATUS,
   MIXTURE_STATUS,
   PLATE_STATUS,
   CS_TERM_REASON,
   ASSAYS_ORDERED,
   ASSAYS_REPORTED,
   AOF_GEN_TS,
   AOF_TRANS_TS,
   AOF_PROC_TS,
   FIRST_TERM_REPORT_TRANS_TS,
   COMPLETE_WITHOUT_REPORT_TS,
   RELATED_CELL_SOURCE,
   FACILITY,
   RELEASED_DATE,
   IHC_DATE, --Error is happening here
   T,
   M,
   N,
   TUMOR_STAGE,
   TUMOR_GRADE,
   TUMOR_DIFF,
   I_COUNT,
   R_COUNT,
   N_COUNT,
   MIXTURE_ID,
   PLATED_TS,
   TREATED_TS,
   FIXED_STAINED_TS,
   SCANNED_TS,
   COUNTED_TS,
   ASSAYS_PLATED,
   CELL_YIELD,
   EXPLANTED_BY,
   REPLATE,
   AVG_CONTROL,
   CELL_SUSPENSION_CREATOR,
   CELL_SUSPENSION_TS,
   IN_CULTURE_TS,
   ENOUGH_CELLS_TS,
   MIXTURE_ON_PLATE_TS,
   TERM_MIXTURE_TS,
   MIXTURE_TERM_REASON,
   COMPLETE_TS,
   VALIDATED_TS,
   SALES_REP,
   DRUG_SEL_TS,
   DRUGS_ON_PANEL,
   FINAL_PATH_COMP_TS,
   PHYSICIAN,
   CELL_SOURCE_TYPE_ID,
   LXWXH,
   PCT_SOLID,
   PCT_FATTY,
   PCT_FIBROUS,
   PCT_BLOODY,
   PCT_NECROTIC,
   PCT_OTHER,
   LESS_THAN_100MG,
   OVERSIZED,
   UNDERSIZED,
   FLASK_TYPE,
   VITROGEN_COATED,
   AB_WASH_REQUIRED,
   DIM_X,
   DIM_Y,
   DIM_Z,
   MANUAL_PLATE,
   LAB_SITE_ABBR,
   REGION_TERRITORY,
   MEDIUM_TYPE,
   TUMOR_TYPE_FP,
   TUMOR_TYPE_PP,
   CR_ENTRY_CREATOR,
   CR_ENTRY_CREATED_TS,
   ICC_ENTRY_CREATOR,
   ICC_ENTRY_CREATED_TS,
   AOF_TRANS_CREATOR
)
AS
SELECT cs.accession_label,
          cs.received_date,
          cs.created_timestamp AS ACCESSIONING_TS,
          PW.TTR_TUMOR_TYPE_INFO,
          VW_CS.SPEC_TYPE,
          VW_CS.TUMOR_TYPE,
          VW_CS.TUMOR_SUBTYPE,
          VW_CS.PRIM_MET,
          VW_CS.TUMOR_SITE,
          VW_CS.EXTRACT_DATE,
          VW_CS.CELL_SOURCE_STATUS,
          VW_CS.MIXTURE_STATUS,
          VW_CS.PLATE_STATUS,
          VW_CS.CS_TERM_REASON,
          VW_CS.ASSAYS_ORDERED,
          VW_CS.ASSAYS_REPORTED,
          VW_CS.AOF_GEN_TS,
          VW_CS.AOF_TRANS_TS,
          VW_CS.AOF_PROC_TS,
          VW_CS.FIRST_TERM_REPORT_TRANS_TS,
          VW_CS.COMPLETE_WITHOUT_REPORT_TS,
          VW_CS.RELATED_CELL_SOURCE,
          VW_CS.VW_CS.FACILITY,
          VW_CS.RELEASED_DATE,
          VW_CS.IHC_DATE,
          VW_CS.T,
          VW_CS.M,
          VW_CS.N,
          VW_CS.TUMOR_STAGE,
          VW_CS.TUMOR_GRADE,
          VW_CS.TUMOR_DIFF,
          VW_CS.I_COUNT,
          VW_CS.R_COUNT,
          VW_CS.N_COUNT,
          MIXTURE.TERM_MC_MIXTURE_ID AS Mixture_ID,
          MIXTURE.PLATED_TS,
          MIXTURE.TREATED_TS,
          MIXTURE.FIXED_STAINED_TS,
          MIXTURE.SCANNED_TS,
          MIXTURE.COUNTED_TS,
          Mixture.Assays_Plated,
          Mixture.CELL_YIELD,
          Mixture.EXPLANTED_BY,
          NVL (Mixture.REPLATE, 0) Replate,
          Mixture.AVG_CONTROL,
          Mixture.CELL_SUSPENSION_CREATOR,
          Mixture.CELL_SUSPENSION_TS,
          Mixture.IN_CULTURE_TS,
          Mixture.ENOUGH_CELLS_TS,
          Mixture.MIXTURE_ON_PLATE_TS,
          Mixture.TERM_MIXTURE_TS,
          Mixture.MIXTURE_TERM_REASON,
          Mixture.COMPLETE_TS,
          Mixture.VALIDATED_TS,
          PW.SALES_REP,
          PW.DRUG_SEL_TS,
          PW.DRUGS_ON_PANEL,
          PW.FINAL_PATH_COMP_TS,
          PW.PHYSICIAN,
          CS.CELL_SOURCE_TYPE_ID,
          VW_CS.LXWXH,
          VW_CS.PCT_SOLID,
          VW_CS.PCT_FATTY,
          VW_CS.PCT_FIBROUS,
          VW_CS.PCT_BLOODY,
          VW_CS.PCT_NECROTIC,
          VW_CS.PCT_OTHER,
          VW_CS.LESS_THAN_100MG,
          VW_CS.OVERSIZED,
          VW_CS.UNDERSIZED,
          MIXTURE.FLASK_TYPE,
          MIXTURE.VITROGEN_COATED,
          VW_CS.AB_WASH_REQUIRED,
          VW_CS.DIM_X,
          VW_CS.DIM_Y,
          VW_CS.DIM_Z,
          MIXTURE.MANUAL_PLATE,
          CS.LAB_SITE_ABBR,
          V2.CRM_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS.STATE REGION_TERRITORY,
          MIXTURE.MEDIUM_TYPE,
          VW_CS.TUMOR_TYPE_FP,
          VW_CS.TUMOR_TYPE_PP,
          MIXTURE.CR_ENTRY_CREATOR,
          MIXTURE.CR_ENTRY_CREATED_TS,
          MIXTURE.ICC_ENTRY_CREATOR,
          MIXTURE.ICC_ENTRY_CREATED_TS,
          VW_CS.AOF_TRANS_CREATOR
     FROM V2.cell_Source cs
          INNER JOIN V2RPT.TEMP_DM_CS_TYPE
             ON CS.CELL_SOURCE_TYPE_ID =
                   V2RPT.TEMP_DM_CS_TYPE.CELL_SOURCE_TYPE_ID
          LEFT OUTER JOIN V2RPT.TEMP_DM_CS VW_CS
             ON CS.CELL_SOURCE_ID = VW_CS.CELL_SOURCE_ID
          LEFT OUTER JOIN V2RPT.TEMP_DM_MIXTURE MIXTURE
             ON MIXTURE.cell_Source_id = CS.CELL_SOURCE_ID
          LEFT OUTER JOIN V2RPT.VW_DM_PW PW
             ON PW.cell_source_ID = cs.cell_source_ID
          LEFT OUTER JOIN V2.CRM_ACCOUNT
             ON V2.CRM_ACCOUNT.CRM_ACCOUNT_ID = CS.CRM_ACCOUNT_ID
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (  SELECT MAX (
                                       V2.CRM_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS.
                                       CRM_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_ID)
                                       Max_AA_ID,
                                    V2.CRM_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS.CRM_ACCOUNT_ID
                               FROM V2.CRM_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS
                           GROUP BY V2.CRM_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS.CRM_ACCOUNT_ID) Max_AA
             ON Max_AA.CRM_ACCOUNT_ID = V2.CRM_ACCOUNT.CRM_ACCOUNT_ID
          LEFT OUTER JOIN V2.CRM_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS
             ON V2.CRM_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS.CRM_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_ID =
                   max_aa.Max_AA_ID;
```

I'm a tad lost -- any ideas?  I mean, there aren't even any variables to assign values to, so I don't know how the 'string buffer can be too small'

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you got any triggers on the database that are firing when the view is created?  To me, the line `error occurred at recursive SQL level 1` suggests an error in a trigger.  Perhaps there's some kind of auditing trigger that is auditing objects being created and the view you created was too large for this trigger to cope with?

Here's a demonstration of how to generate an error similar to yours when creating a view.  First, we create a trigger that causes a `character string buffer too small` error when you attempt to create something.  Chances are that the trigger that appears to be causing your problem isn't quite this stupid:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger error_trigger
  2    before create on database
  3  declare
  4    a varchar(1);
  5  begin
  6    a := '12';
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Now, when we attempt to create a view, we get an error:

```
SQL> create view some_view as select * from dual;
create view some_view as select * from dual
                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

This view has nothing to do with PL/SQL or character string buffers, nor does it even have a line 4, but we still get the above error because of the trigger we created.  With this trigger, line 1 (`declare`) is the first line of the trigger itself, as opposed to the `create trigger` statement that creates it, so line 4 is the line `a := '12';`.

To track down this trigger, we can query the `dba_triggers` data dictionary view.  In the example below, it turns up in the bottom row:

```
SQL> select trigger_name, trigger_type, owner from dba_triggers
  2   where trigger_type in ('BEFORE EVENT', 'AFTER EVENT');

TRIGGER_NAME                   TRIGGER_TYPE     OWNER
------------------------------ ---------------- ------------------------------
AW_DROP_TRG                    AFTER EVENT      SYS
AW_TRUNC_TRG                   AFTER EVENT      SYS
AW_REN_TRG                     AFTER EVENT      SYS
XDB_PI_TRIG                    BEFORE EVENT     SYS
SDO_DROP_USER                  AFTER EVENT      MDSYS
SDO_ST_SYN_CREATE              BEFORE EVENT     MDSYS
SDO_TOPO_DROP_FTBL             BEFORE EVENT     MDSYS
ERROR_TRIGGER                  BEFORE EVENT     LUKE
```

Comment: As odd as this sounds -- for some reason, the schema name I was using to log in with couldn't create the trigger -- however, when I changed names, I was able to create it no problem.

Thanks for the help though, much appreciated.